# How to change variable in "Many to Many" relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with many to many relationship:

```
t1
ID(PK)   NAME     VISIBLE
1        John     1
2        Sam      1
3        Kurt     0
---------------------------
t2
ID(PK)   NAME      VISIBLE
1        Product1  1
2        Product2  0
---------------------------
t3
IDt1(FK)  IDt2(FK)   VISIBLE
1         1          1
2         1          1   
3         2          0
```

So, What I need:

When I change visible in t1, the column `visible` in `t2` changed too, if they are connected in `t3` table.

For example: When I set `Kurt`(`visible = 0`) in `t1`, product2 should automatically set `Product2`(`visible = 0`), because they are connected in `t3` table.

How to do this with FK's when designing database?

Or is it fundamentally wrong?

Comment: What should happen with `Product1` if you set `John (visible = 0)`, but `Sam` is still `visible = 1`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel it should to change to `visible=0` anyway.

Comment: So a product is always not visible if any of related names (from `t1`) is not visible? And when you change `John` back to visible `Product1` should change to visible too?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel If any connected value  in  t3 `= 0`, value in t2 should to be `=0` too.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel but anyway, I will do this programmatically.

Comment: Well.. then it's not possible to solve with FKs, because the value in `t2` depends on multiple rows in `t1`. However.. since that column contains redundant (dependent) data, you should consider to skip it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the FK you can not do that. The aim of usage of FK is different, it helps to check relation or dependency of data with PK. It is helpful when deleting the PK and dependent FK data.

Maybe you can achieve this design using triggers on the table, however, it is not the right way to do this on database level. It will create performance issues. Instead, you should do this programmatically.